# How to open several tables in different tabs in SQL Developer

Tags: tabs, sql, sqldeveloper

I have several schemes and need to open different tables in different tabs from different schemes at the same time.

SQL Developer opens the table view in the same tab.

Clicking whilst holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After a table is opened in a tab, pin it ( ie, click on pin ) to freeze the view of the table on that tab. Repeat the same for other tables you wish to open.

Answer (score 27):

Folow these steps:

- Tools
- Preferences
- Database
- ObjectViewer Parameters
- Automatically Freeze Object Viewer Windows

Then restart SQL developer

Comment: this doesnt answer the question, but it's what i was looking for so thanks :)

Comment: @niahoo This does answer the question.  In fact, it's probably exactly what the asker wanted, despite not receiving the checkmark.  It might not be the best answer ever, but in my opinion it's the right answer.  At the very least, it's my preferred behaviour.

Comment: @MBraedley Well I think the accepted answer is the good one because it explains the mechanism of pinning despite any configuration. But yeah I like this behaviour too. Cheers :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since no other manual steps are required.